# Failed to create Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, directx, vertex-buffer

When I try to create an vertex buffer, it fails and the `HRESULT` value is `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. The source code is the following:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA bufferData;

bufferData.pSysMem = NULL;
bufferData.SysMemPitch = NULL;
bufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = NULL;

bufferDesc.ByteWidth = 1024 * sizeof(SpriteVertex);
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = NULL;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = NULL;
bufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(SpriteVertex);

pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &bufferData, &m_pVertexBuffer);
```

Does someone has an idea why this error appears?

Comment: Try passing `NULL` for for the `pInitialData` argument in `CreateBuffer`.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.

Comment: If you enable the Debug device, then you will see explanations of things like ``INVALID_ARGUMENT`` in the output window. Also, you are using ``NULL`` in a number of places that aren't pointers. Use 0 for values, ``nullptr`` for pointers, and avoid legacy ``NULL``.

Comment: NULL is defined as 0 at least in my IDE (VS2015)